# Problem with sending image using TCP/IP Bi-directional chatting apps

Tags: c#, image, tcpclient

I am fairly new to c# and this is my first time setting up a chatting apps using TCP/IP connection.

In my codes, I want the server and the client to be able to send images and text. However, there is a problem when sending an image where in the GUI, the image sent was displayed in terms of "weird symbol". The GUI consists of a pictureBox where when it is clicked, the client or the server can select images they want to send. Then the messages send will be displayed on the flowlayoutpanel.

This is the codes for the server:

```
using SimpleTCP;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace TCPIPChat
{
    public partial class Server : Form
    {
        private bool Connect_Button_Clicked = false;
        public List<string> chat_history = new List<string>();
        
        public Server()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Thread thread = new Thread(EstablishConnection)
            {
                IsBackground = true,
            };
            thread.Start();
        }

        public void EstablishConnection()
        {
            TcpListener server = null;
            try
            {
                /*Set TCP listener on port 13000*/
                Int32 port = 13000;
                IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Any;
                server = new TcpListener(localAddress, port);
                server.Start();

                /*Buffer for reading data*/
                Byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
                String data = null;

                while(true)
                {
                    /*Perform blocking call to accept requests*/
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                    /*Change Disconnect Button Colour if client request connection*/
                    Connect1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        Connect1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                        Connect1.Text = "Connected";
                        Connect_Button_Clicked = true;
                    }));
                    data = null;

                    /*Get a stream object for reading and writing */
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                    int a;
                    
                    while((a = stream.Read(bytes,0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        //Translate data bytes to an ASCII string
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, a);
                        chat_history.Add("[Client ]: " + data);
                        LeftLabel(data);

                    }
 
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException c)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", c);
            }
            finally
            {
                server.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void LeftLabel(string data)
        {
            string input = data;
            Label Server_Label = new Label();

            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.Controls.Add(Server_Label);
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Server_Label);
            }));

            Server_Label.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                Server_Label.Text = input;
                Server_Label.BackColor = Color.Black;
                Server_Label.ForeColor = Color.White;
                Server_Label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                Server_Label.Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 4);
                Server_Label.AutoSize = true;
            }));

            Console.WriteLine(data);
        }


        public static string GetIPAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if(ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("No IPv4 Address detected!");
        }
        

        static void Connect(String server, String message)
        {
            try
            {
                /*Int32 port = 13001;
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
                Console.WriteLine("(Me): {0}", message);
                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
               
                
                //Get Client Stream/Writing 
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                
                //Send message to connected TCP server
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                
                //Close All
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
                */

                Int32 port = 13001;
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
                Console.WriteLine("(Me): {0}", message);
                if (IsBase64String(message))
                {
                    //Received message is image
                    Byte[] imageReceived = Convert.FromBase64String(message);

                    NetworkStream stream1 = client.GetStream();
                    stream1.Write(imageReceived, 0, imageReceived.Length);

                    stream1.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    //If text is received
                    Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                    NetworkStream stream2 = client.GetStream();
                    stream2.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    stream2.Close();
                }
                client.Close();

            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }
        }

        static bool IsBase64String(string input)
        {
            try
            {
                
                byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
                return true;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void SendButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Connect_Button_Clicked)
            {
                string input = textReceive1.Text;
                if(input != "")
                {
                    chat_history.Add("[Server]:" + input);
                    RightLabel(input);
                    textReceive1.Clear();
                    Connect(GetIPAddress(), input);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No connection detected. Please make sure your client is connected to this server!");
            }
        }

        private void RightLabel(string input_data) 
        {
            string input = input_data;
            Label Mylabel = new Label();
            this.Controls.Add(Mylabel);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Mylabel);
            Mylabel.Text = input;
            Mylabel.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen;
            Mylabel.ForeColor = Color.White;
            Mylabel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            Mylabel.Margin = new Padding(flowLayoutPanel1.Width - Mylabel.Right, 0, 0, 4);
            Mylabel.AutoSize = true;
        }

        private void ExportButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream myStream;
            SaveFileDialog save1 = new SaveFileDialog();

            save1.Filter = "txt files (.*txt)|*.txt";
            save1.FilterIndex = 2;
            save1.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (save1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if((myStream = save1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter(myStream);
                    foreach(string s in chat_history)
                    {
                        txt.Write(s + "\n");
                    }
                    txt.Close();
                    myStream.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Image Files (*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.bmp)|*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.bmp";

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string selectedImagePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
                SendImage(selectedImagePath);
            }
        }

        private void SendImage(string imagePath)
        {
            if (Connect_Button_Clicked)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] imageData = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
                    string base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageData);
                    Connect(GetIPAddress(), base64Image);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error sending image: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No connection made, please press Connect!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the codes for the client:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class Client : Form
    {
        private bool Connect_Button_Clicked = false;
        public List<string> chat_history = new List<string>();

        public Client()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Thread thread = new Thread(EstablishConnection)
            {
                IsBackground = true,
            };
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void Connect_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connect_Button_Clicked = true;
            if (Connect_Button_Clicked)
            {
                ConnectToServer();
            }
        }

        static void ConnectToServer()
        {
            Connect(GetIPAddress(), "");
        }

        public static string GetIPAddress()
        {
            var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (var ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if(ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            throw new Exception("No IPv4 Address detected!");
        }

        static void Connect(String server, String message)
        {
            try
            {
                Int32 port = 13000;
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
                if(IsBase64String(message))
                {
                    //Received message is image
                    Byte[] imageReceived = Convert.FromBase64String(message);

                    NetworkStream stream1 = client.GetStream();
                    stream1.Write(imageReceived,0, imageReceived.Length);
                    
                    stream1.Close();


                }
                else
                {
                    //If text is received
                    Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
                    NetworkStream stream2 = client.GetStream();
                    stream2.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    stream2.Close();
                }
                
                

                //Get Server for reading/writing
                //NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                //new

                //Send messages to connected server
                //stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                //close all
                //stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }
        }

        static bool IsBase64String(string input)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(input);

                return true;
            }
            catch(FormatException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void Send_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Connect_Button_Clicked)
            {
                string input = textReceive2.Text;

                if (input != "")
                {
                    chat_history.Add("[Client ]: " + input);
                    RightLabel(input);
                    textReceive2.Clear();
                    Connect(GetIPAddress(), input);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No connection made, Please press connect!");
            }

        }
        public void EstablishConnection()
        {
            TcpListener server = null;
            try
            {
                Int32 port = 13001;
                IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Any;
                server = new TcpListener(localAddress, port);
                server.Start();

                //Buffer for reading data
                Byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
                String data = null;

                while(true)
                {
                    //Perform blocking call to accept requests
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    data = null;

                    //Get stream object for reading/writing
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                    int a;
                    while((a = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, a);
                        LeftLabel(data);
                        chat_history.Add("[Server]: " + data);
                    }
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch(SocketException c)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", c);
            }
            finally
            {
                server.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void RightLabel(string input_data)
        {
            string input = input_data;
            Label mylabel = new Label();
            this.Controls.Add(mylabel);
            flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(mylabel);
            mylabel.Text = input;
            mylabel.BackColor = Color.DarkGreen;
            mylabel.ForeColor = Color.White;
            mylabel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            mylabel.Margin = new Padding(flowLayoutPanel2.Width - mylabel.Right, 0, 0, 4);
            mylabel.AutoSize = true;
        }

        private void LeftLabel(string data)
        {
            string input = data;
            Label serverlbl = new Label();

            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.Controls.Add(serverlbl);
                flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(serverlbl);
            }));

            serverlbl.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                serverlbl.Text = input;
                serverlbl.BackColor = Color.Black;
                serverlbl.ForeColor = Color.White;
                serverlbl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                serverlbl.Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 4);
                serverlbl.AutoSize = true;
            }));
        }


        private void Export_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream stream;
            SaveFileDialog saveChat = new SaveFileDialog();

            saveChat.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            saveChat.FilterIndex = 2;
            saveChat.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if(saveChat.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if((stream = saveChat.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter(stream);
                    foreach(string chat in chat_history)
                    {
                        txt.Write(chat + "\n");
                    }
                    txt.Close();
                    stream.Close(); 
                }
            }

        }
        private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Image Files (*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.bmp)|*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.bmp";

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string selectedImagePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
                SendImage(selectedImagePath);
            }
        }

        private void SendImage(string imagePath)
        {

            if (Connect_Button_Clicked)
            {
                try
                {
                    byte[] imageData = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
                    string base64Image = Convert.ToBase64String(imageData);
                    Connect(GetIPAddress(), base64Image);
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error sending image: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No connection made, please press Connect!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what happen when I try to send an image.  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0K8i.jpg)

What should I do to fix this? I want to send a single image just like a normal chatting apps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be aware that TCP doesn't do *messages*. It does an *endless stream of bytes* in each direction. This means that calls to Send at one end are not matched 1-1 with calls of Receive at the other end. You can send 200, 300, then 100 bytes and receive that as 1 receive of 600 bytes. Or 600 receives of a single byte each. Or anywhere in between. If you want *messaging*, you either have to implement message framing yourself in TCP or pick a higher level protocol that does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are not programming / thinking like a programmer, and it has ZERO relevance to you being new to C#.... that is fundamental.

The issue is that you have ONE connection (which is ok) and you expect the client to magically know that the following is an image, while not doing ANY programming to handle the bytes that come and treat them as an image. So you dump them onto the text output and magically expect the UI to handle this.

Time to step back and do a more professional communication layer. At least define a protocol between both sides that allows you to sensibly program code that isolates the binary payload and treats it different. You send the image as Base64 - good, but you seem to lack any demarcation to identify start and end of the image.  How is the client supposed to know that the ascii symbols coming from now on are part of a Base64 encoded binary and not someone typing funny? Look up how i.e. Emails handle this.

And maybe "being new to C#" in 2023 you do not follow extremely outdated code examples - thread start on that is bad, really bad. Async is a thing in C# for a long time by now. Oh, and do not dump a ton of code on us - isolate the problem.